# How do I copy all data, limiting cells to 72 characters, into a new workbook?

Tags: excel, vba, copy

I need to upload from Excel to SAP.

Active Workbook has the columns H, I, J, M and N.

SAP only recognizes text with max length of 72 letters. Column from H to J and M will never have more than 72 letters.

From
[image]

To
[image]

Create new workbook and save as name.

Copy H, I, J, M and N from active Workbook to new workbook to A, B, C, D, E.

When text in N has more letters than 72, create new row in new Workbook with the same information from range A to D and continue text from N after 72 letters from active row.

Continue procedure until the full text from E is now in separated rows of 72 letters.

```
Sub Copy_Value_ofBox()

Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet
Dim lngLastRow As Long: lngLastRow = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count

'eine neue Datei erstellen / create new workbook with Filename

Set wb = Workbooks.Add

With wb
.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\X1YKapla\Desktop\Yunus Kaplan\02 
Tätigkeiten\011 Translation\02 Upload Files\Translation 
Upload Language___ and Date___.xlsm" _
, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False

'.SaveAs Filename:= Source - wo soll es gespeichert werden und nach dem     
backslash Datei name zb. "JAN 2012.xlsx" _
   , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

wb("Translation Upload Language___ and Date___.xlsm").ws.Range("H1:J1").Copy 
_ wb("Kopie von Template_Translation").ws.Range("A1")

.ChangeFileAccess Mode:=xlReadOnly, WritePassword:="Translation"

End With

'Übersetzte texte - Copy Title in new Workbook

ws.Range("H1").Copy Destination:=ws.Range("A1")
ws.Range("I1").Copy Destination:=ws.Range("B1")
ws.Range("J1").Copy Destination:=ws.Range("C1")
ws.Range("M1").Copy Destination:=ws.Range("D1")
ws.Range("N1").Copy Destination:=ws.Range("E1")

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

I was able to create a new file and save as name.

I wasn't able to copy any data from active wb to the new wb.

Answer (score 1):

Explanation in code comments.

```
Option Explicit

Sub MakeSAPws()

    Dim fn As String, str As String, i As Long, j As Long, p As Long, mxt As Long, tmp As Variant

    fn = "C:\Users\X1YKapla\Desktop\Yunus Kaplan\02 Tätigkeiten\011 Translation\02 Upload Files\Translation Upload Language___ and Date___"
    mxt = 72   'maximum text length

    'when you copy a worksheet without a destination it creates a new
    'workbook with a copy of that worksheet
    ActiveSheet.Copy

    With ActiveWorkbook

        'save as filename assigned above
        .SaveAs Filename:=fn, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled

        'there is only one worksheet
        With .Worksheets(1)

            'optionally change new worksheet name
            .Name = "blah-blah"

            'delete unwanted columns
            .Range("A:G, K:L, O:XFD").EntireColumn.Delete

            'loop through rows backwards splitting column N
            For i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
                'reset p
                p = mxt
                'assign column N to str
                str = .Cells(i, "E").Value
                'make pieces of column N split on spaces less than 72 chars
                Do While p < Len(str)
                    p = InStrRev(str, Chr(32), p, vbBinaryCompare)
                    str = Application.Replace(str, p, 1, Chr(9))
                    p = p + mxt
                Loop
                'create array of column N pieces
                tmp = Split(str, Chr(9))
                'create additional rows if required
                For j = UBound(tmp) To LBound(tmp) + 1 Step -1
                    .Cells(i + 1, "A").Resize(1, 5).Insert shift:=xlDown
                    .Cells(i + 1, "E") = tmp(j)
                    .Cells(i, "A").Resize(2, 4).FillDown
                    .Cells(i, "E") = tmp(LBound(tmp))
                Next j
            Next i

        End With

        .ChangeFileAccess Mode:=xlReadOnly, WritePassword:="Translation"
        .Close savechanges:=True

    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

YOu need to declare both the old and new workbooks so you can readily swap between them.  Example code would be:

```
dim wbs as workbook, wbd as workbook
set wbs = activeworkbook 'workbook: source
set wbd = createobject("Excel.Application") 'workbook: destination
```

You can then utilize pulling data from one and push into another.  This would be different than `save as` which has only one workbook, but changes filepath location.

---

Regarding movign your data, use value=value to speed up your process, such that:

```
wbd.range(wbd.columns(1),wbd.columns(3)).value = wbs.range(wbs.columns(8),wbs.columns(10)).value
```

Comment: Thank you for your recommendations and advices. Please check the Pictures i've just added.